# change workflow due time based on priority level sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

As the title says I am looking for the way to change the due time of a Workflow item based in the Pirority Level, for example:

High: 4 Days

Medium: 7 Days

Low: 10 Days

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In workflow, you create a local variable of type date and set the variable by adding number of days to Today based on priority. Finally set the task due date with the dueDate local variable.

Here are the steps you do.

**Create a local variable**

[image]

**Create you workflow stage**

[image]

**Set Due Date in the Assign Task Window**

[image]